# Programatically remove radio button and display only text

Tags: android, radio-button, drawable

I have a radio button with text displaying like this:

`0 About` ,here 0 indicates that its a radio button, i want to progrmatically remove radio button and display only text "About" how to do this?

I have tried :

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);// only hides the radio button
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.empty);// not working
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont u just setVisablity(View.GONE); ?

Comment: I don't understand `// only hides the radio button`

Comment: @mc_fish setVisablity(View.GONE); ? will also remove the text

Comment: @njzk2 it will not be visible , but it will be present

Comment: Use radioButton and textView(to show the text).. then use radioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE)..

Comment: oh the "About" is the label of the radio...yeah...u cant do that...2 options: custom view or 2 views separate

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your intent, do you want to have a `TextView` that behaves like a `RadioButton`? or do you want a `RadioButton` that only shows it's image component when switched 'on'? Most likely you could mimic what you're after by sing 2 separate controls.

Comment: @LouisSherwood thanks, currently i want the radio button to be hidden , i have tried with radioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent); but the text wil not be placed in center since the radio button is by default placed towards left, how to solve this?

Comment: there should be a checkMark attribute to the radiobutton. try to set it to transparent?

Comment: @njzk2 nope :( any other solution?

Comment: why do you use radiobuttons if you don't want the radio icon ? why not use a toggle button ?

Comment: i am working on tab feature, so we have to go with radio button, there is also other option text view behave like radio button but i have not got anything on this

Answer (score 1):

- Have you tries the following line to the hide the button drawable:

  `radioButton.setButtonDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFFFFFF));`

this will hide the drawable on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

xml layout:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ButtonText" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

To hide radiobutton:

```
    radioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: It will also hide the text

Comment: I don't understand why this `radioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);` does not work. Can you clarify the question, maybe provide some imeges of what you need.

Comment: This will only hide the radio button from but it will take that space

Comment: I think that @CRUSADER is right.  
I'll update my answer with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can setText at runtime using setText() method

radioButton.setText("About");

May be you want this.

Answer (score 0):

Just dont set text at all to `RadioButton` and use separate `TextView` as its text.

Then when you want to hide RadioButton just use `setVisibility(View.GONE);` (View.GONE will hide the whole thing, no space at all there) and to show it again `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Here's a little example with layout of how to use it:

XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Radio button text" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toggle visibility" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(radioButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            radioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(radioButton.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            radioButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank for you help , but i have a problem here like i am using 3 radio button to be placed one after the other in a radiogroup